# globalThis not defined after git hiccup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been working on a web app in React. I was following [this guide](https://python.plainenglish.io/python-in-react-with-pyodide-a9c45d4d38ff).

In order to execute Python code in the app, and I was able to get it successfully working.

However, I went to `git add *` and forgot I hadn't yet added a `gitignore`, so it added the `node_modules` and package/lock files.

Idioticly, I did `git -rm *` and it deleted everything, but I still had my relevant code windows open so I just saved those and then added back react scripts/yarn install etc.

Eventually I got it running but started getting the error:

```
'globalThis' is not defined  no-undef
```

I tried looking online but most issues revolved around outdated Node versions. My Node is v16.13.1, plus I just had it working so clearly this was not the issue.

I even created an entirely new React project and copied over my code, but I still run into the same error. I tried npm install globalthis and yarn add globalthis, tried restarting my computer, and even tried re-installing node but the issue persists.

I am at a total loss for what to do. I know the issue is not with my code because it was it was working previously before the git mistake.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with an eslint rule. Read the fix here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15199#issuecomment-948724014

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your eslint config. ([This might be helpful](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11553#issuecomment-476570950))

```json
{
  "globals": {
    "globalThis": false,
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually wasn't using eslint, but I configured it and added this to the config. I now get an error in the browser: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): globalThis.loadPyodide is not a function. In VSCode, when I highlight globalThis and click go to definition, it says it's undefined so I think this is just a different way of telling me the same thing.